# SQL Full Outer Join

Tags: sql, join

I am trying to write a join statement to join the following three data sets together. (This is using MS SQL Server)

```
Set 1
ID    Date    Col1 
1     Jan 11  a1 
1     Jan 13  a2

Set 2
ID    Date    Col2 
1     Jan 11  b1 
1     Jan 15  b2

Set 3
ID    Date    Col3
1     Jan 15  c1 
1     Jan 17  c2

Combined Set
ID    Date    Col1    Col2    Col3
1     Jan 11  a1      b1
1     Jan 13  a2
1     Jan 15          b2       c1
1     Jan 17                   c2
```

I think a full outer join is able to do this but I am running into major cross product issues.

Comment: what major cross product issues are you running into?

Comment: This data structure & combined data is confusing.  ID is the same across all rows? What is the FK that relates these Sets?  What have you tried & what issue are you receiving?

Comment: Agree. I think he doesn't need the ID in the result table, though.

Comment: To add some details. I just included one ID in fact there are many IDs. I am looking at medical data so the ID is the PatientID. Set 1 is prescription so the date is the medication start date. Set 2 are lab results so the date is the Observation date. Set 3 are appointments the date is the appointment date. I am trying to get a complete set of data to generate some reports.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Give this a try:

```
select coalesce(t1.date, t2.date, t3.date) date, col1, col2, col3 from table1 t1
full outer join table2 t2 on (t1.date = t2.date)
full outer join table3 t3 on (t2.date = t3.date)
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on your dataset, you seem like you want to join the 3 tables based on the `date` column. Note that I'm disregarding the ID column here, until you clarify why all the IDs are set to 1.

```
SELECT ISNULL(set1.dt, ISNULL(set2.dt, set3.dt)) as 'Date', col1, col2, col3
FROM set1
FULL OUTER JOIN set2 ON CAST(set1.dt AS DATE) = CAST(set2.dt AS DATE)
FULL OUTER JOIN set3 ON CAST(set2.dt AS DATE) = CAST(set3.dt AS DATE)
```

Comment: See comment at the top explaining the IDs.

Answer (score 1):

`SELECT ISNULL(a.ID,isnull(b.ID,c.ID)) ID,coalesce(a.dt, b.dt, c.dt) , Col1, Col2, Col3
FROM set1 a
FULL OUTER JOIN set2 b ON a.dt = b.dt
FULL OUTER JOIN set3 c ON b.dt= c.dt`