# SQL Full Outer Join duplicate Issue

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, join, outer-join

I've been searching this over quite a bit, and I just can't see where I'm going wrong.  I'm hoping someone can help me figure it out.  I have two tables, one for all the Sales Orders (SO) for a part number, one for all the Purchase Orders (PO) for a part number.  I want to merge the results together.  Most of the times, there will not be the same number of Purchase Orders and Sales Orders per part.  In this example, I have 2 Sales Orders and 1 Purchase order.

```
Table 1 (SO)
Company     Part     SalesOrder
ABC         123       5530
ABC         123       6854
ABC         456       7772
ABC         456       6868

Table 2 (PO)
Company     Part     PurchaseOrder
ABC         123       9889
ABC         456       9308
ABC         456       9655
ABC         456       9774
```

I would expect to see:

```
Company     Part     SalesOrder     PurchaseOrder
ABC         123       5530            9889
ABC         123       6854            NULL
ABC         456       7772            9308
ABC         456       6868            9655
ABC         456       NULL            9774
```

But I am seeing:

```
Company     Part     SalesOrder     PurchaseOrder
ABC         123       5530            9889
ABC         123       6854            9889
ABC         456       7772            9308
ABC         456       7772            9655
ABC         456       7772            9774
ABC         456       6868            9308
ABC         456       6868            9655
ABC         456       6868            9774
```

This is my query:

```
 select coalesce(SO.Company, PO.Company) as Company,
 coalesce(SO.Part, PO.Part) as Part, 
 SO.SalesOrder, PO.PurchaseOrder 
 from  SO full outer join PO
 on SO.Company=PO.Company and SO.Part=PO.Part
```

Maybe it's not a full outer join that I need to achieve this?  For reference, I looked at posts like 
[SQL Full Outer Join](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13447570/sql-full-outer-join) and I thought that my desired results look similar to those in the post, and I thought my query looks like the chosen solution, but obviously I am failing somewhere.  I greatly appreciate any help.

----Update----
I think I am causing some confusion, and for that, I apologize.  Just to clarify, the PO's and SO's have no relation to each other than they are for the same part.  A particular PO is NOT getting created to fulfill a particular SO.  Some parts may ONLY have SO's (for example, manufactured parts) some might have ONLY PO's (component parts to a manufactured item).  Some parts will happen to have the same number of SO's and PO's by coincidence, but most of the time, there will probably be more than one or the other.  For example, if I wanted to look at a part's historic activity, there might be 4 sales orders for it, and 1 purchase order for it.  If I were to do a union where I basically clumped the 'activity' (SO's/Po's) into one column, then for that part, the query would return 5 rows of activity (4 SO's/ 1 PO).  But instead of having 1 column and 5 rows, could I make it to where I would have 2 columns (one for SO's and one for PO's) and have 4 rows?  All rows in the SO column would not be null, and 4 would be null for PO's and one would not.  It's just a visual preference to have the first row to contain the PO row that is not null, but in no way, is the SO and PO of row one actually related, other than that they happen to be on the same row.

To give an entirely different example:

Lets say I have a customer table, and a vendor table, and they both have the field names of 'Name' and 'State' and I want to make a list of all my customers or vendors that are in California.  I could do a union right?

```
select c.name, 'Cust' as Type, c.state
from customer c 
where c.state='CA'
union
select v.name, 'Vend', v.state
from vendor v
where v.state='CA'
```

and I would get something like:

```
Name          Type     State
BB Shrimp     Cust     CA
Vista Inc     Cust     CA
Mary's Lamb   Cust     CA
Cali Coffee   Cust     CA
Cool Guys     Cust     CA
Tap Corp      Vendor   CA
Blue Supply   Vendor   CA
Sun Shore     Vendor   CA
```

But I wanted to see this instead:

```
Vendor       Customer     State
Tap Corp     BB Shrimp     CA
Blue Supply  Vista Inc     CA
Sun Shore    Mary's Lamb   CA
NULL         Cali Coffee   CA
NULL         Cool Guys     CA
NULL         Tap Corp      CA
```

I could see where you would ask, why would I ever want to see that, but if I had data presented that way, I could throw it into SSRS and make it look like

```
 State   Vendors      Customers  
 CA      Tap Corp     BB Shrimp 
         Blue Supply  Vista Inc                 
         Sun Shore    Mary's Lamb                           
                      Cali Coffee   
                      Cool Guys
```

Now switch State for Part, Vendor for PO, and Customer for SO, and that's what I am trying to achieve.  Vendors and Customers have no relation other than being from the same state, some states might have more vendors than customers, they might have the same, but its unrelated.  Same goal with PO and SO.

Comment: This is how joins work. 2 rows from the Left with 3 rows from the Right =6. What do you want here exactly? In fact you'd only get nulls if a row doesn't appear in one of the tables.

Comment: I do not understand what is the reasoning for this result: `ABC         123       6854            NULL` Are you just basing that on row number?

Comment: Hi. "merge the results together" doesn't mean anything. Say what you mean. Why is that table what you "would expect to see"? What *definition* of full join are you using? Why don't you reference one? Why give a link not containing one? Plus you don't say what output you *want* in terms of input  (although you give an example), so how do we know what you want anyway, regardless of what full join does? Please edit your post into the best possible current presentation. Don't append new text. Adding more doesn't make something unclear any clearer.

Comment: PS PLease don't give an explanation about why you want what you want. (Let alone a rambling one). Just tell us what you want.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems like you want to pair off POs and SOs based on their sequence, but FULL OUTER JOIN is going to just pair them up in all possible combinations. If you want to capture the order, you need to do a ROW_NUMBER() first:

```
SELECT COALESCE(SO2.company, PO2.company) AS Company,
       COALESCE(SO2.part, PO2.part)       AS Part,
       so.salesorder,
       po.purchaseorder
FROM   (SELECT *,
               Row_number()
                 OVER (
                   partition BY so.part, so.company
                   ORDER BY so.salesorder) AS SO_Sequence
        FROM   so) AS SO2
       FULL OUTER JOIN (SELECT *,
                               Row_number()
                                 OVER (
                                   partition BY po.part, po.company
                                   ORDER BY po.purchaseorder) AS PO_Sequence
                        FROM   po) AS PO2
                    ON SO2.company = PO2.company
                       AND SO2.part = PO2.part
                       AND SO2.so_sequence = PO2.po_sequence
```

Comment: I don't want to technically pair SO's and PO's.  If you could image a union query instead, just using part '123'.  As a union, with the SO/PO # being a shared column, it would return 3 rows, correct?  Now imagine that, but instead of returning 1 column, 3 rows, I want to return 2 columns (SO/PO) and 2 rows (2 rows due to the highest count of either SO's or PO's being 2.  Lets say a part had 10 PO's and 3 SO's, I want the two columns (one for SO's, one for PO's) and 10 rows, none of the PO's would be null but 7 out of the 10 rows SO's would be and to me, it wouldn't matter which rows were null.

Comment: @jenhil34 Imagine testing the solution

Comment: @NaveedHasan - COALESCE  use for Return the first non-null value in a list

Example: SELECT COALESCE(NULL, NULL, NULL, 'W3Schools.com', NULL, 'Example.com');

Answer (score 2):

This is the nature of OUTER JOIN.  Your LEFT table is your SO.  Foreach row in SO you have a part number and order number, and will receive a row in your result set.  Once all the LEFT rows are evaluated, sql will evaluate rows in the RIGHT table, hence you get a row in the result set for each row in both table sets.

The reason you see

```
Company     Part     SalesOrder     PurchaseOrder
ABC         123       5530            9889
ABC         123       6854            9889
```

Instead of

```
Company     Part     SalesOrder     PurchaseOrder
ABC         123       5530            9889
ABC         123       6854            NULL
```

Is because it still matched on part number and company.

The OUTER JOIN is the correct way to get the results you are looking for, but your current relation model isn't definitive enough to achieve the goal correctly.

If you are supposed to have a 1::1 relationship, you should have either a PO id in the SO table, or SO id in the PO table.

@Greg Viers has shown a way to assign the PO id of the first occurrence in the PO table of your company/part combo to the first occurrence in the SO table.  However, in almost every business case ever it is possible to fill orders out of the order they are received. Also do your orders not have quantities?  Your current set up leaves lots of gaps in your data relationships.

As well as this is much more difficult to maintain on the data side as well; for example, what happens if a purchase order gets cancelled?

Answer (score 1):

I see that you are relying on the order of rows in first table to find the Purchase Order for a given Sales Order, is it functionally correct. How do you know that the single purchase order in the second table is corresponding to first Sales order only? can't it be for the second record? That's the reason your expected result itself is ambiguous.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32258706)

Answer (score 0):

I just focused on Row 2 and Row 5 from your expected Result . I think Row 5 expected NULL for SalesOrder is wrong, I think it should be 6884 . 
Here is the logic to back my claim . I dont know how you got the result but i tried same query i am getting your expected result

```
CREATE TABLE #SO ( 
Company NVARCHAR(16),
PART NVARCHAR(16),
SalesOrder NVARCHAR(16) ) 

INSERT INTO #SO VALUES('ABC','123','6854')
INSERT INTO #SO VALUES ('ABC','456','6868')



CREATE TABLE #PO ( 
Company NVARCHAR(16),
PART NVARCHAR(16),
PurchaseOrder NVARCHAR(16) ) 

INSERT INTO #PO VALUES('ABC','456','9308')
INSERT INTO #PO VALUES ('ABC','456','9774')

select * from #SO 
SELECT * FROM #PO


SELECt coalesce(PO.COMPANY, SO.COMPANY) as Company 
     , coalesce(SO.PART, PO.PART) as Part 
     , SO.SalesOrder,po.PurchaseOrder 
      FROM #SO AS SO 
                FULL OUTER JOIN #PO AS PO
                 ON  PO.PART = SO.PART AND 
          PO.Company = SO.Company
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the Union for this. I have added the script with the union

```
SELECT Company, Part, SalesOrder, number = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(Partition By Company,Part ORDER BY Company,Part) 
INTO #TEMP_SO
FROM SO

SELECT Company, Part, PurchaseOrder, number = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(Partition By Company,Part ORDER BY Company,Part) 
INTO #TEMP_PO
FROM PO

SELECT s.Company, s.Part, s.SalesOrder, p.PurchaseOrder FROM #TEMP_SO s
LEFT JOIN #TEMP_PO p ON p.Part = s.Part AND p.Company = s.Company AND p.number = s.number

UNION

SELECT p.Company, p.Part, s.SalesOrder, p.PurchaseOrder FROM #TEMP_PO p 
LEFT JOIN #TEMP_SO s ON p.Part = s.Part AND p.Company = s.Company AND p.number = s.number

DROP TABLE #TEMP_PO
DROP TABLE #TEMP_SO
```

Answer (score 0):

First Create the temp table for all the required columns and fill those columns by insert/update.

Here we can check with the number of rows. if the number of rows match, update the column of customer else insert the new row.

FOR YOUR Customer and vendor example you can use script as below:

```
-- create the final columns temp table
CREATE TABLE #Temp
(
    ID INT primary KEY identity(1,1),
    Vendors VARCHAR(200),
    Customers VARCHAR(200),
    State VARCHAR(200)
)

-- insert the vendor & state columns
INSERT INTO #Temp (Vendors, Customers,State)
SELECT name, NULL, state  FROM vendor

-- create customer temp table with row numbers
SELECT num = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY name), * 
INTO #Temp_Customer
FROM Customer c

-- update temp table's customer column if the temp tables row number = customer's row number
UPDATE T
SET T.Customers = c.name
FROM #Temp T
INNER JOIN #Temp_Customer C ON c.num = T.ID

-- insert into temp table for customer's record(if customer has row more than the temp table)
INSERT INTO #Temp (Vendors, Customers,State)
SELECT NULL, c.name, c.state
FROM #Temp_Customer C
LEFT JOIN #Temp T ON c.num = T.ID
WHERE T.ID IS NULL


SELECT * FROM #Temp

DROP TABLE #Temp
DROP TABLE #Temp_Customer
```

[image]

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097 PS Answers without explanation are poor. [answer] [Help]